# Почему df -h, df -a и mount отдают разный результат?

Tags: linux

Делаю df -h

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
tmpfs                       7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
//10.10.10.1/filestorage    485G  2.7G  482G   1% /mnt/filestorage/b
tmpfs                       1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Делаю df -a

```
Filesystem                 1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
debugfs                            0       0         0    - /sys/kernel/debug
sunrpc                             0       0         0    - /run/rpc_pipefs
/usr/sbin/auto.filestorage         0       0         0    - /mnt/filestorage
//10.10.10.1/filestorage   507944172 2830708 505113464   1% /mnt/filestorage/c
tmpfs                        1643564       0   1643564   0% /run/user/1000
//10.10.10.1/filestorage   507944172 2830708 505113464   1% /mnt/filestorage/b
//10.10.10.1/filestorage   507944172 2830708 505113464   1% /mnt/filestorage/a
binfmt_misc                        0       0         0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

Делаю mount

```
/usr/sbin/auto.filestorage on /mnt/filestorage type autofs ...
//10.10.10.1/filestorage on /mnt/filestorage/c type cifs ...
//10.10.10.1/filestorage on /mnt/filestorage/b type cifs ... 
//10.10.10.1/filestorage on /mnt/filestorage/a type cifs ...
```

В частности, меня интересует, почему df -h показывает только одну шару?

Comment: `man df` ответит на ваш вопрос: `-a`, `--all` Включает в список файловых систем те, которые имеют размер в 0 блоков, и которые по умолчанию опускаются. Такие файловые  системы  обычно являются  псевдо-файловыми системами специального назначения, например, для automounter.  Кроме того, только если задана эта опция, будут показаны файловые системы типа "ignore" или "auto", которые поддерживаются некоторыми операционными системами. А ключ -h это приведение значений к человеческому виду, т.е. использовать `df -ah` вполне законно

Comment: @PotroNik а это не является тем, что данные точки монтирования неправильно примонтированы или есть ошибки в монтировании?

Comment: На мой взгляд нет, у вас по факту одно удаленное хранилище смонтировано на несколько точек, а так как `df` - **отчёт об использовании дискового пространства**, то вероятнее всего ссылаться на один и тот же раздел несколько раз ему не обязательно, достаточно отобразить лишь по одному. Ну и скорее всего это так же зависит от версии программы